# How to include a php file in a file which is already included in many other pages PHP

Tags: php

Can it be possible to include a `PHP` file into another file which is already included in many other files on **different paths**

For example I have the following files and directories:

```
domain/include/header.php
domain/include/body.php
domain/include/user_data.php
```

`header.php` file contains `user_data.php` and `header.php` file itself contained in many other pages on different location:

```
domain/index.php
domain/home/index.php
domain/home/user/index.php
```

I want to access my `user_data.php` file within one(*i.e header.php*) and don't want to include it again and again in each file.

How is this possible?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah why not. You can create master include file and that file includes all other files from the directory.

So your **header.php** file will look something like this,

```
<?php
    include('user_data.php'); // Assuming file is in same location.
```

Now include only `header.php` file where every you want, it will automatically includes `user_data.php` along with it.

**Extra:**

This is useful for including database connection files.

You can also use this file include root level JS and CSS so you don't have include those assets on every page.

---

Using [include_once()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) is good practice, as if you have included `user_data.php` file somewhere in other files and it also gets include from the `hedaer.php` file, It won't get included twice.

As that is all **include_once()** does, it includes the file content only once per execution.

> The only difference between **include()** and **include_once()** that
>   if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be
>   included again, and include_once returns **TRUE**.

Answer (score 0):

see `include_once` and `require_once`

Comment: May be OP is not looking for `include_once`.

Comment: Well, if you could clarify, I could edit my answer. The question clearly states he doesn't want to include the contents more than once even though he wants to access it in multiple files. I'd be happy to extend my answer if you have any other interpretation though.

Comment: From my interpretation of the question, OP wants to create master include file which includes other files and then use that single mast include file in every page.

Comment: The problem with that though is that it may become very complex if he does not want to add some includes that are in the master include. This will turn into a brain overload spaghetti pretty quickly. However, for simple projects, it might suffice.